# Strange behavior of Beamer overlay specification in RTL language

Tags: beamer, enumerate, overlays, arabic, right-to-left

The famous `[<+->]` overlay specification is not working as expected in this very simple MWE right-to-left beamer presentation.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq,abjadjimnotail=true]{arabic} % Polyglossia package for more options
\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits,Ligatures=TeX]{Simplified Arabic}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits,Ligatures=TeX]{Simplified Arabic} % Bold sans used for sections
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Arial}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][right]
\usetheme{Frankfurt} 
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\title{مثال توضيحي}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage%
\end{frame}

\section{مقدمة}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{الشريحة الاولى}

  \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
    \raggedleft%
  \item هنا النقطة الاولى
  \item الثانية حيث اكتب ١، ٢، ٣، ٤، ٥
  \item الثالثة والاخيرة
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

In the first overlay, the first item is active and the second one is inactive so far which is good, but the third item text and bullet alike should be inactive as the second one. In this case only the bullet is inactive while the text is not.

By the second overlay, the second item becomes active as expected.

Finally, by the third overlay, the third item bullet and not the text is becoming active, the text has already been active right from the beginning. So could you please help me fix this abnormal behavior?

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce this problem without special fonts like `Amiri`? This probably would increase the number of people who can compile your code and try to help you.

Comment: font was changed to `Simplified Arabic`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a line break after the last item of your list, this problem is produced only in right to left context (I don't know  what causes this)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq,abjadjimnotail=true]{arabic} % Polyglossia package for more options
\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits,Ligatures=TeX]{Simplified Arabic}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits,Ligatures=TeX]{Simplified Arabic} % Bold sans used for sections
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Arial}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][right]
\usetheme{Frankfurt} 
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\title{مثال توضيحي}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage%
\end{frame}


\section{مقدمة}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{الشريحة الاولى}

  \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
   \raggedleft%     
  \item هنا النقطة الاولى
  \item الثانية حيث اكتب ١، ٢، ٣، ٤، ٥
  \item الثالثة والاخيرة

  \end{enumerate}

  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
   \raggedleft%     
  \item هنا النقطة الاولى
  \item الثانية حيث اكتب ١، ٢، ٣، ٤، ٥
  \item الثالثة والاخيرة

  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```