# Beamer+Polyglossia(bidi)+RTL with xelatex breaking footnote overlay

Tags: beamer, xetex, polyglossia, hebrew, bidi

I have seen from other answers ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47332) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357927/31561)) that  `bidi` (from `polyglossia`) does not play nice with `beamer` and RTL languages. This is indeed an example of this. However, I am curious if there is a fix.

When I include a RTL language, the footnote overlay seems to break when compiled with `xelatex`. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[
  ignorenonframetext,
]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\usetheme[]{metropolis}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage[url=false]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}

  This is some text.\footnote<.->{This is a footnote}
  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is a MWE, so pretend that I need the overlay.

Just including the `\setotherlanguage{hebrew}` breaks the footnote overlay when compiled with `xelatex`. This is what is produced:

[image: Broken]

If you comment that line out, everything works:

[image: Correct]

Is there an easy way to fix this?

UPDATE:

As pointed out by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz in a comment, this works with `lualatex`. However, `lualatex` seems to do weird things with lists and RTL (as pointed out by @udi-fogiel in a comment). Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[
  ignorenonframetext,
]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\usetheme[]{metropolis}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew,Contextuals=Alternate,Ligatures=Required,ItalicFont={SBL      Hebrew}]{SBL Hebrew}
\usepackage[url=false]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}

\begin{itemize}
\item This is some text.\footnote<.->{This is a footnote}
\pause
\item \texthebrew{בְ} - this should not be right justified
\pause
\item But \texthebrew{בְ} should also be left justified

\end{itemize}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

When compiled with `lualatex`, this is the result, which makes the list right justified if the first letter is a RTL language:

[image]

Comment: Works fine with lualatex: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg7is.png I would not use xelatex with beamer, it causes a lot of other problems as well.

Comment: Unrelated, you don't need `\usepackage{amsmath}`, beamer already loads this for you

Comment: I am using pandoc, which includes amsmath for beamer. Don't ask me why

Comment: Hmm that  is true about lualatex. However, it messes up when I try to do RTL in lists. I would have to go figure out RTL lists with lualatex

Comment: Can you show an example? Maybe that's easier to fix.

Comment: `polyglossia` use the `luabidi` package for r2l typesetting with luatex, but this package is currently not really maintained and has a lot of problems. If you want to use luatex, use babel with the `bidi=basic` option.

Comment: @Paul You can have all your items on the left with `\item \mbox{}\texthebrew{בְ} - this should not be right justified`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I updated the question with another MWE for lualatex.

Comment: @Paul See my comment above

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks, I saw it. That does work. I will do that for now, but will leave the question open for now to see if there is an answer for xelatex.

Comment: @Paul Have fun with all the other problems of xelatex+beamer! :) (missing text on note pages, incorrect text opacities ...)